# How to conditional format a column when it partially matches another

Tags: excel

first question here.
I have two columns.

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| MNR6788 | 6788 |
| NJI89076 | 9089 |
| GHJ9089 | 89076 |
| ZZZ-909-8907 | 9087654 |
| DFGT9098743 | 98756436 |

I want to conditional format a cell in COL1 when it partially matches any cell in COL2.
All data is randomised.

Example:
MNR6788 matches with 6788, so it gets highlighted

NJI89076 matches with 89076 so it gets highlighted (they are not in same row)

I tried using

```
=O:O
```

in the custom formula text box, but to no avail.

So to summarise, I basically want to tell excel to match each cell in COL2 with each cell in COL1, and highlight corresponding cell in COL1 if there is any match.

Can a  formula like

```
=(partially matches any cell in COL2)
```

to put in the conditional formatting condition be achieved? I have been trying to  do something like this for a long time now.

Comment: I don't know why the github style table ain't showing, should I edit it?

Comment: Yes, indeed you should post a good data example, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You can count how many values of COL2 partically match with value in COL1, and sum up. If result>0, then highlight.

I've created a Conditional Formatting Rule based on this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2;"*"&$B$2:$B$6&"*"))>0
```